# Which vehicle can carry the most passengers in GTA IV

Tags: grand-theft-auto-iv

I wanted to know which land vehicle can carry the most number of passengers in GTA IV.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, in GTA IV, there is no vehicle that can hold more than 4 people (Niko and 3 passengers). Even the Bus cannot have more than 3 passengers in it.

Vehicles which can hold 4 are extremely common- anything with 4 doors will.